# Spark iterative/recursive algorithms - Breaking spark lineage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a recursive spark algorithm that applies a sliding window of 10 days to a Dataset.

The original dataset is loaded from a Hive table partitioned by date.

At each iteration a complex set of operations is applied to Dataset containing the ten day window.

The last date is then inserted back into the original Hive table and the next date loaded from Hive and unioned to the remaining nine days.

I realise that I need to break the spark lineage to prevent the DAG from growing unmanageable.

I believe I have two options:

1. Checkpointing - involves a costly write to HDFS.
2. Convert to rdd and back again

   spark.createDataset(myDS.rdd)

Are there any disadvantages using the second option - I am assuming this is an in memory operation and is therefore cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check pointing and converting back to RDD are indeed the best/only ways to truncate lineage.

Many (all?) of the Spark ML Dataset/DataFrame algorithms are actually implemented using RDDs, but the APIs exposed are DS/DF due to the optimizer not being parallelized and lineage size from iterative/recursive implementations.

There is a cost to converting to and from RDD, but smaller than the file system checkpointing option.

Comment: What say you have a loop with DF.read? How does lineage work then? @Garren S

Comment: If I understand your question, an application that loops over with many read calls where each read is independent of the last, lineage should not be a problem as each read would be its own job . If you keep converting the same dataset to RDD then back, the lineage would be truncated.

Comment: OK, gotcha. Reading this question made we wonder. That clarifies it. Nice weekend.

Comment: Does converting to an rdd and then calling `createDataFrame` collect the rdd to the driver? I've only used `createDataFrame` on local data on the master, I'm trying this now and it is crashing with out of memory on the driver - not sure if it is this `createDataFrame` call yet

Comment: I have a similar need to truncate the dag in each iteration as my udf call keep increasing with every iteration. I have to avoid checkpoint and cache. Is converting to rdd and back an optimal solution and will it truncate the dag.