# what if I use an action like createdataframe() to break a very long lineage rather than checkpoint?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

What if I break the long lineage using an action like mentioned below rather than checkpoint:

**myDataframe.sqlContext().createDataFrame(myDataframe.toJavaRDD(), myDataframe.schema()).cache()**

What impact will it have?

Comment: Also, I found this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750413/spark-createdataframedf-rdd-df-schema-vs-checkpoint-for-breaking-lineage

Comment: But i think, the myDataframe.sqlContext().createDataFrame(myDataframe.toJavaRDD(), myDataframe.schema()).cache() will have an issue with respect to the fault tolerance.